# Angular ng-repeat with nested json objects?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object, represented as such:

```
 {
  "orders" : [
    {
      "ordernum" : "PRAAA000000177800601",
      "buyer" : "Donna Heywood"
      "parcels" : [
        {
          "upid" : "UPID567890123456",
          "tpid" : "TPID789456789485"
        },
        {
          "upid" : "UPID586905486090",
          "tpid" : "TPID343454645455"          
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ordernum" : "ORAAA000000367567345",
      "buyer" : "Melanie Daniels"
      "parcels" : [
        {
          "upid" : "UPID456547347776",
          "tpid" : "TPID645896579688"
        },
        {
          "upid" : "UPID768577673366",
          "tpid" : "TPID784574333345"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to do a repeater on the **second** level of this, a list of the "upid" numbers.

I know already how to get the top level

`<li ng-repeat="o in orders">{{o.ordernum}}</li>`

But I am unclear on the sequence to loop a level down.  For example, this is wrong:

`<li ng-repeat="p in orders.parcels">{{p.upid}}</li>`

I also know how to *nest* repeaters to get this, but in this case i don't need to display the top level at all.

**CLARIFICATION**

The goal here is to have one list with the 4 "upid" numbers (there are 2 for each parcel, and there are 2 parcels in the order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching a lot for nice and simple solution for iterating dynamically. I came up with this

JAVASCRIPT (angular): a person is an example of nested object. the is_object function will be use in the HTML view.

```
$scope.person = {
    "name": "john",
    "properties": {
       "age": 25,
       "sex": "m"
    },
    "salary": 1000
}

// helper method to check if a field is a nested object
$scope.is_object = function (something) {
    return typeof (something) == 'object' ? true : false;
};
```

HTML: define a template for simple table. the 1st TD is the key which is displayed. another TD (2 or 3, but never both) will be show the value if its not an object (number / string), OR loop again if its an object.

```
<table border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="(k,v) in person">
    <td> {{ k }} </td>
    <td ng-if="is_object(v) == false"> {{ v }} </td>
    <td ng-if="is_object(v)">
        <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v">
                <td> {{ k2 }} </td>
                <td> {{ v2 }} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just create new array 'parcels' like in demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "orders": [{
      "ordernum": "PRAAA000000177800601",
      "buyer": "Donna Heywood",
      "parcels": [{
        "upid": "UPID567890123456",
        "tpid": "TPID789456789485"
      }, {
        "upid": "UPID586905486090",
        "tpid": "TPID343454645455"
      }]
    }, {
      "ordernum": "ORAAA000000367567345",
      "buyer": "Melanie Daniels",
      "parcels": [{
        "upid": "UPID456547347776",
        "tpid": "TPID645896579688"
      }, {
        "upid": "UPID768577673366",
        "tpid": "TPID784574333345"
      }]
    }]
  };

  $scope.parcels = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data.orders, function(order) {
    angular.forEach(order.parcels, function(parcel) {
      $scope.parcels.push(parcel)
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="o in parcels">{{o.upid}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the data being loaded externally, see http://plnkr.co/edit/2WnMcwxcmTVA8luquWM9?p=preview

since `$scope.data.orders` doesn't exist then.  I am loading the orders via a factory.

Comment: This would still work even if loading in data from a factory. You would just have to map the new array when the data comes in. Keep the scoped variable the same, then just change that variable to the new array when the data comes in.

Edit: This is the best way to do it, the other answers are unnecessarily heavy and/or wont work.

Comment: This works great! But, how would I alter the filter to access a **third** level in the JSON?

Comment: @Bice can you please provide sample plunkr ?

Comment: Sure: http://plnkr.co/edit/qY4yoBsGTjl9HsreivAN?p=info I also submitted this as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637599/accessing-3rd-level-of-json-with-angular-ng-repeat?noredirect=1#comment55049699_33637599

Answer (score 5):

Actually its same answer of @sylwester. The better way to put it in `filter`. And you can reuse it by passing propertyName parameter.

In your case we passed `parcels`

**JS**

```
myApp.filter('createarray', function () {
    return function (value, propertyName) {
        var arrayList = [];
        angular.forEach(value, function (val) {
            angular.forEach(val[propertyName], function (v) {
                arrayList.push(v)
            });
        });
        return arrayList;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="o in ordersList.orders | createarray: 'parcels'">{{o.upid}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w00eo4bz/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you just need a double-nested for loop -

```
<ul>    
  <div ng-repeat="o in orders">
    <li ng-repeat="p in o.parcels">{{p.upid}}</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

The HTML might be a little ugly here, but I'm not sure what exactly you are going for. Alternatively you could just create a new array of the `parcels` via mapping.

Comment: That answer would give me 2 uls, each with 2 LIs.

Comment: I am looking to make one UL with the 4 parcels.

Comment: @Steve Like I said, I dont know how specifically you want the output. Plus, you always have the options of mapping to a new array.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer.  Sorry if the original question was confusing.

Comment: @Steve Updated, should fit your bill

Comment: `div` inside `ul` won't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Comment: @DavidGrinberg technically it shouldn't be there

Comment: how would this same principle apply to a select menu's ng-options?

Comment: @Steve In that case you would need to map it out to a new array of parcels, or create a custom directive.

Comment: I was trying to do that just now, using @sylwester answer, modified.  But I guess I have the for loop wrong http://plnkr.co/edit/2WnMcwxcmTVA8luquWM9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `<li ng-repeat="p in orders.parcels">{{p.upid}}</li>` does not work the way you expect is because the parcels array is an object inside each individual order in your order array, i.e. it is not an object of the orders array itself.

If your orders array is defined on the $scope of a controller, then you create the array on the `$scope` variable:

```
$scope.allParcels = $scope.orders
    .map(function (elem) {
         return elem.parcels;
    }) // get an array where each element is an array of parcels.
    .reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue.concat(currentValue);
     }); // concat each array of parcels into a single array of parcels
```

then on the template, you can use `<li ng-repeat='p in allParcels'>{{p.upid}}</li>`

If, however, you do not want to place the array on the `$scope`, I believe you can do something similar to this:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in orders
     .map(function (elem) {
         return elem.parcels; 
      })
     .reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
          return previousValue.concat(currentValue);
     })">{{p.upid}}</li>
```

although I'm not 100% sure that Angular will evaluate the .map/.reduce in the `ng-repeat` expression (also having an array generated this way in an `ng-repeat` is ill-advised since angular would have to constantly generate a new array via map/reduce on each `$digest` cycle).

Comment: Wow.  That is incredibly complicated. But thanks for the detailed explanation, I had no idea.