# bootstrap dropdown and nanoscroller JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, nanoscroller

Something really annoying is happening when I use a  Bootstrap dropdown and the nanoscrollerJS plugin. The nanoscroller plugin is not triggered when you dropdown the menu. It instead triggers as soon as you use firebug and go over the dropdown again. It looks like the dropdown is hidden in the DOM even though it was triggered. How can nanoscroller be triggered properly?

Nanoscroller: https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/spw1khad/

The code:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <div id="about" class="nano">
        <div class="nano-content">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </div>
    </div>  
            </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a little markup comment; you use a `<div>` tag directly after a `<ul>` tag, this is incorrect. I improved this part in the code below.
See also [Can I use div as a direct child of UL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul)

Now your problem, it seems like bootstrap triggers some js function at the moment you click the dropdown button which causes to 'crash' nanoscroller. Using a click event with a time out is a bit hacky but it does the job for you.

**html part**

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>

</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <div id="about" class="nano">
        <div class="nano-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the js part:**

```
$('#dropdownMenu1').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".nano").nanoScroller();
    }, 100);
});
```