# Text on top of text in css?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I put Font Awesome icons (FB, Twitter, Steam) that look like images but are actually text in my footer, and I added some other linked text. Now my footer shows the icons next to the text, but I want my icons to be on top of the text and centered just like this site: [see footer here](http://www.csgoshuffle.com/howto). This website also has hover, and I know the command for that, but I don't know where to include it.

My code:

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 87px;
    background-color: #212022;
    border-bottom:2px groove #cc9900;
}
main {
  background-color: #181719;
}

.centered {
    margin: 160px auto;
    padding:30px 50px;
    width: 800px;
    color: #efefef;
    background: #1c1b1d;
    border: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
.centered h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 164px;
  background-color : #212022;
  border-top: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
p{
  color: white
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "csgofontlight"
 src: url('../fonts/csgofontlight.tff') format('truetype');
 }
#logo{
 width: 520px;
 height: 80px;
 background: url<'/StaffPage/img/logo.png'> no-repeat scroll center;
 margin-top:3px;
        left: 108px;
        float: left;
 position: absolute;
        text-indent:-9999px;
}
#steamlogin{
 width: 154px;
 height: 23px;
 background: url('/StaffPage/img/steamlogin.png');
 margin-top: 34px;
        right: 108px; 
        float: right;
 position: absolute;
        text-indent:-9999px;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px
} 
header ul {
   list-style:none;
  margin:33px auto;
  width:600px;
  text-align:center;
}
header ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
header ul li a {
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 300px;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  color: #E6E6E6;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
#howto {
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 400px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:50px auto;
  width:1000px;
  position: absolute; top: 620px; right: 310px;
}
footer ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
footer ul li a {
  color: #717171;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
footer ul li a:hover {

  color: #DADADB;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
h2 {
  font : 20px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
main ul li {
  font : 15px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #949494;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSGOShuffle Staff Team</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StaffPage/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/StaffPage/icon.ico" />
<body class="Site">
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="logo"></div>
         <a href="//csgoshuffle.com" id="logo">Range Web Development</a>
     <div id="steamlogin"></div>
        <a href="//csgoshuffle.com/login" id="steamlogin">Range Web</a>
   </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
        <li><a id="howto" href ="//csgoshuffle.com/howto" target="_blank">How to Play</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main class="Site-content">
    <div class="centered">
        <h2>STAFF TEAM</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Our mod chimbobway can deal with all missing skins deals , his account link is </li>
        <h2>Missing Value , here is fix</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Our Mod Chimbobway will add you </li>
            <li>You will recive a case ID from the mod</li>
            <li>You Have to provide the mod with screen shots of all the info that he needs</li>
            <li>All Trades must has Code that the mod gonna give it to you</li>            
     </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
     <ul>
       <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <li><a  href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle">  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC'></i></li>
      <li><a  href="//twitter.com/csgoshuffle">  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></li>
      <li><a  href="//steamcommunity.com/groups/">  <i class="fa fa-steam fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></li>
      
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/status">Status</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/provably-fair">Provably Fair</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com/kb">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/tos">Terms of Service</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//store.steampowered.com/">Powered by Steam</a></li>
      
      
    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGNYGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was a bit unresponsive but we will only undress the problem you have. Let's see.

For starters you have to close your elements, just for good practice. Your `<footer>` could be like this.

```
<footer>

    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle"> <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style='color: #CCCCCC'></i></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="//twitter.com/csgoshuffle"> <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="//steamcommunity.com/groups/"> <i class="fa fa-steam fa-2x" style='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></a></li>
    </ul>



    <ul>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/status">Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/provably-fair">Provably Fair</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="//support.csgoshuffle.com/kb">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/tos">Terms of Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="//store.steampowered.com/">Powered by Steam</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

I removed the unnecessary div and i split the `<ul>` in 2 `<ul>`s, the icons and the text.

Now for the css

Remove the fixed height from `<footer>`

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color : #212022;
  border-top: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
```

Also, remove **floats**, and **absolute positioning** from your icons

```
#logo{
    width: 520px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url<'/StaffPage/img/logo.png'> no-repeat scroll center;
    margin-top:3px;
}
#steamlogin{
    width: 154px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url('/StaffPage/img/steamlogin.png');
    margin-top: 34px;
}
```

Finally, I made your `<ul>` displaying as `block` and removed fixed `width`

```
footer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style:none;
  margin:50px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

That should auto-align eveything according to your needs, without the need of explicitly position everything for every different display width.

*Update* you could change `margin:50px auto;` to `margin:0px auto;` to get a closer look in what you want

*Update 2* as for the hover effect

You should remove the style from your `<li>` `<a>`s e.g.

```
<li><a href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle"> <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
```

and add it in your css like this

```
footer ul li a i{
    color: #CCCCCC
}
```

then you just have to change this rule

```
header ul li a:hover
```

to this

```
footer ul li a:hover i
```

e.g.

```
header ul li a:hover i{
    color: #E6E6E6;
    -o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
    -khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
    -ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
    transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
```

here is the working snippet

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 87px;
    background-color: #212022;
    border-bottom:2px groove #cc9900;
}
main {
  background-color: #181719;
}

.centered {
    margin: 160px auto;
    padding:30px 50px;
    width: 800px;
    color: #efefef;
    background: #1c1b1d;
    border: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
.centered h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color : #212022;
  border-top: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
p{
  color: white
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "csgofontlight"
 src: url('../fonts/csgofontlight.tff') format('truetype');
 }
#logo{
 width: 520px;
 height: 80px;
 background: url<'/StaffPage/img/logo.png'> no-repeat scroll center;
 margin-top:3px;
}
#steamlogin{
 width: 154px;
 height: 23px;
 background: url('/StaffPage/img/steamlogin.png');
 margin-top: 34px;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px
} 
header ul {
   list-style:none;
  margin:33px auto;
  width:600px;
  text-align:center;
}
header ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
header ul li a {
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 300px;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  color: #E6E6E6;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
#howto {
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 400px;
}

footer ul {
  display: block;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
footer ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
footer ul li a {
  color: #717171;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

footer ul li a i{
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

footer ul li a:hover i{

  color: yellow;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
h2 {
  font : 20px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
main ul li {
  font : 15px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #949494;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSGOShuffle Staff Team</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StaffPage/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/StaffPage/icon.ico" />
<body class="Site">
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="logo"></div>
         <a href="//csgoshuffle.com" id="logo">Range Web Development</a>
     <div id="steamlogin"></div>
        <a href="//csgoshuffle.com/login" id="steamlogin">Range Web</a>
   </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
        <li><a id="howto" href ="//csgoshuffle.com/howto" target="_blank">How to Play</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main class="Site-content">
    <div class="centered">
        <h2>STAFF TEAM</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Our mod chimbobway can deal with all missing skins deals , his account link is </li>
        <h2>Missing Value , here is fix</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Our Mod Chimbobway will add you </li>
            <li>You will recive a case ID from the mod</li>
            <li>You Have to provide the mod with screen shots of all the info that he needs</li>
            <li>All Trades must has Code that the mod gonna give it to you</li>            
     </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>

    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle"> <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="//twitter.com/csgoshuffle"> <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="//steamcommunity.com/groups/"> <i class="fa fa-steam fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    </ul>



    <ul>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/status">Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/provably-fair">Provably Fair</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="//support.csgoshuffle.com/kb">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="//csgoshuffle.com/tos">Terms of Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="//store.steampowered.com/">Powered by Steam</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: hey jonathan 
i just have couple questions about the code

Comment: i see how u made 2 <ul> s in the footer one for icons and one for links 
and in the css we made a hoover just for the icons 
if i want to make another hoover for the links 
where i gonna type that command , i mean they booth in footer and they booth ul li a , am i right ? 
thats why i got confused , i dont know whats the diffrecne between the command for the icons and the links 
i hope you know what iam talking about :) if u didnt i can explain what i mean

Comment: i forgot to mention you xD @Jonathan La'Fey

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. When we say `header ul li a:hover i` we mean that, when we hover over a an `<a>` of a `<li>` of a `<ul>` of a `<footer>`, then you do something on `<i>`. The 2nd `<ul>` has no i so you need to add a 2nd rule: `header ul li a:hover`

Comment: Cool bro thx  i will test that , sorry if i asked something stupid but iam kinda new , i used w3school to learn codes , and i didnt find every thing iam looking for in there . but thx god i found this site

Comment: No it's fine! Sorry for yhe late answers

Comment: so i reached this code , and i had 2 pic's in the header , now only the one on the right appears and the one on the left doesnt , do you have any idea why this thing happening ? 
this is how the code looks like so far 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGNYGK
and this is pic from the header on my site shows that i have the right pic but the left 1 missing 
http://prntscr.com/864240

Comment: oh never mind i had <> around my link and it must be () i fixed it ! thx

Comment: 1 more question please its just about placing this text 
you see "How to play" between the center box and the header on this site https://csgoshuffle.com/howto
i want to put that but i dont know where i type the html code for it 
 i tried to put it in the header , but i fail cuz the text start going over the box when i scroll down :( 
and i tried to put it inside the box then push it up with some px commands and position but it stays inside the box 
any idea please ?

Comment: Again, it's not gonna be very responsive, but you could do something like that:

in your class `.centered` add **in the end** a style `margin-top: 30px;`

then, **right after** `main` element **and before** `div` with class `.centered` add this:


`<div style="margin-top: 120px; text-align: center"><a style="color:#DDD; text-decoration:none; font-size: 1.6em" href ="//csgoshuffle.com/howto" target="_blank">How to Play</a></div>`

by now you should now how to move the inline styles to the css file :)

Comment: Bear in mind, that this could be way more easier if you could separate each _part_ of your html in a different _container_. Meaning that `<main>`, for example, should not _contain_ or _overlay_ the `header` etc.

Comment: bro thx for help i know i asked you alot of questions , cuz i have low skills with codes , but believe me iam searching for fix before i ask you . and you really helping me to improve my coding skill ,
what i reached so far is this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGdYNM
and what iam trying to make is this http://prntscr.com/86i5hy
i tried to make it but i failed 
what i failed in is 
making owner on left and Co-Owner on  right then have text under them and the click here image 
i tried to make it but "Owner" was going out side the text and the text wasnt going under Co-Owner @Jonathan :D help bro

Comment: @MDub I can't provide so much of a code, especially in comment section. It's too specialized. You should try to develop what you can and open a new question. I am sure more people would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap the icons inside a separate div
2. Wrap the links inside a separate div
3. The footer is not centered. Remove `position: absolute` and top and left. That should center your footer
4. Remove `.pull-right` class from the `.navbar-text` and add `text-align: center`.  Do the same for the div containing the links

As for the the hover effect.

1. Remove the inline-style on the icons in your HTML file
2. Add the selector for the icons `footer, .navbar-text, .fa:hover` then apply the color you wish them to change to on hover

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSGOShuffle Staff Team</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StaffPage/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/StaffPage/icon.ico" />
<body class="Site">
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="logo"></div>
         <a href="//csgoshuffle.com" id="logo">Range Web Development</a>
        <div id="steamlogin"></div>
        <a href="//csgoshuffle.com/login" id="steamlogin">Range Web</a>
   </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
        <li><a id="howto" href ="//csgoshuffle.com/howto" target="_blank">How to Play</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main class="Site-content">
    <div class="centered">
        <h2>STAFF TEAM</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Our mod chimbobway can deal with all missing skins deals , his account link is </li>
        <h2>Missing Value , here is fix</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Our Mod Chimbobway will add you </li>
            <li>You will recive a case ID from the mod</li>
            <li>You Have to provide the mod with screen shots of all the info that he needs</li>
            <li>All Trades must has Code that the mod gonna give it to you</li>            
     </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
     <ul>
       <div class="navbar-icon">
      <li><a  href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle">  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC'></i></li>
      <li><a  href="//twitter.com/csgoshuffle">  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></li>
      <li><a  href="//steamcommunity.com/groups/">  <i class="fa fa-steam fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></i></li>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar-text">
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/status">Status</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/provably-fair">Provably Fair</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com/kb">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/tos">Terms of Service</a></li>
      <li><a href ="//store.steampowered.com/">Powered by Steam</a></li>
       </div>


    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 87px;
    background-color: #212022;
    border-bottom:2px groove #cc9900;
}
main {
  background-color: #181719;
}

.centered {
    margin: 160px auto;
    padding:30px 50px;
    width: 800px;
    color: #efefef;
    background: #1c1b1d;
    border: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
.centered h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 164px;
  background-color : #212022;
  border-top: 1px groove #cc9900;
}
p{
  color: white
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "csgofontlight"
 src: url('../fonts/csgofontlight.tff') format('truetype');
 }
#logo{
    width: 520px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url<'/StaffPage/img/logo.png'> no-repeat scroll center;
    margin-top:3px;
        left: 108px;
        float: left;
    position: absolute;
        text-indent:-9999px;
}
#steamlogin{
    width: 154px;
    height: 23px;
    background: url('/StaffPage/img/steamlogin.png');
    margin-top: 34px;
        right: 108px;   
        float: right;
    position: absolute;
        text-indent:-9999px;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px
} 
header ul {
   list-style:none;
  margin:33px auto;
  width:600px;
  text-align:center;
}
header ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
header ul li a {
  color: #949494;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 300px;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  color: #E6E6E6;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
#howto {
  position: absolute; top: 34px; right: 400px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:50px auto;
  width:1000px;
  position: absolute; top: 620px; right: 310px; 
  text-align:center;
}
footer ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
footer ul li a {
  color: #717171;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size : 100%;
  font : 17px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
footer ul li a:hover {

  color: #DADADB;
-o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-khtml-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
-ms-transition: color 0.25s linear;
transition: color 0.25s linear;
}
h2 {
  font : 20px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}
main ul li {
  font : 15px "csgofontlight" , Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #949494;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
```

Comment: Using `<div>` as direct child of  `<ul>` is invalid [though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following changes in your footer:

HTML

```
<footer>
    <ul>       
     <li><a  href="//facebook.com/csgoshuffle" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC'></a></li>
     <li><a  href="//twitter.com/csgoshuffle" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></a></li>
     <li><a  href="//steamcommunity.com/groups/" class="fa fa-steam fa-2x" style ='color: #CCCCCC;'></a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
     <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/status">Status</a></li>
     <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/provably-fair">Provably Fair</a></li>
     <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href ="//support.csgoshuffle.com/kb">FAQ</a></li>
     <li><a href ="//csgoshuffle.com/tos">Terms of Service</a></li>
     <li><a href ="//store.steampowered.com/">Powered by Steam</a></li>     
   </ul>
</footer>
```

I have just divided the list into two lists, one containing the icons and the other for the remaining options. Also included the class and style-related information in the anchor `<a>` tag itself.

And also these following changes in your stylesheet.

CSS

```
footer ul 
{
   margin:auto;
   width:1000px;
   top: 620px; right: 310px;
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Here, I removed the constraint for the absolute position and set the margin to auto for proper indentation to display.

Comment: For the hover effect simply remove the hard coded color for the icons given using the style attribute. (i.e. remove the style="color:#CCCCCC" from all icon list elements ).