# Container within slider breaks slider (Slick.js)

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, slick.js

I'm using [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), a very versatile JQuery carousel plugin.

However the effect I'm trying to accomplish requires me to nest an extra element within the slider. This extra element ends up breaking the slider functionality.

Here's [the page in question](http://rvr.searchanddevelop.ca/). Note how I have a blurred `after` pseudo element blocking the right side of the carousel *(image below depicts current workaround, not the desired effect)*.

[image: current layout]

I'd like the `ul` that holds all the carousel `<li>`'s to be partially covered on the right side using a child element whose overflow is hidden.

So it would look something like this:

[image: after effect]

```
<ul class="slick-slider">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="slick-list">
        <div class="slick-track">
         <li class="slick-slide">carousel item content</li>
         <li class="slick-slide">carousel item content</li>
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

and `.container` would have CSS like

```
.container {overflow: hidden; display: block; width: 90%; border-right: 1px solid #fff;}
```

The only challenge is that this breaks the carousel.
I've tried applying the overflow CSS to the already existing `.slick-list` element, but the parent elements automatically resize everything else in the slider when I do this.

Any ideas on how I can get the slider to ignore the container I want to nest?

EDIT: Here's a gif of me applying the overflow to the parent container and it automatically resizing (the `div.cardoverflow` is a parent of the `<ul>` in this example). I've also tried to do this by adding a `margin-left` to the `<ul>` and it still automatically resizes.

[image: gif animation of slick slider resizing]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have `div` elements as direct children of `ul`. [Can I use div as a direct child of UL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11755628/5297207)

I don't understand why your container can't be outisde of the `ul`, with overflow hidden? And just put the arrow outside them both?

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <button class="slick-prev-arrow" />
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="slider">
                 <li>slide1</li>
                 <li>slide2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button class="slick-next-arrow" />
</div>
```

Note that Slick lets you choose your arrow elements if you want, so you can place them anywhere in your HTML, they don't even have to be buttons (although that's probably better for accessibility).

```
$('ul.slider').slick({
    nextArrow:'.slick-next-arrow',
    prevArrow:'.slick-prev-arrow'
});
```

Comment: That's true. But adding an element outside of the `<ul>` also auto-resizes the whole slider. I'll add an image of this to my original post.

Comment: Added the .gif to better illustrate the auto-resizing I'm referring to.

Comment: I achieved what you need using negative margins as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/vyf2fuwd/2/ Notice I converted your elements to DIVs, as apparently Slick doesn't really support list elements, not while maintaining proper syntax anyway. https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/926    If this works for you I'll update my answer