# How can I add a container <div> after <ul> tag and close container </div> before</ul> close

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="flexslider" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_458">
    <ul class="slides" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_457">
        <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_456">hello</li>
        <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_476">hello</li>
        <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;">hello</li>
        <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;">hello</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_462">
        <li><a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_461"><a class="next" href="#" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_460">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can i add a container div for ul flex-direction-nav with the jquery
like

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_462"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.flexslider .flex-direction-nav').wrap($('<div class="container">'));
```

```css
.container ul {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexslider" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_458">
  <ul class="slides" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_457">
    <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_456">hello</li>
    <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_476">hello</li>
    <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;">hello</li>
    <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none;">hello</li>
  </ul><br>
  <ul class="flex-direction-nav" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_462">
    <li><a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_461"><a class="next" href="#" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443528053909_460">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use [**`wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('.flexslider .flex-direction-nav').wrap($('<div class="container">'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery wrapInner() method
Code is like this 
$('.flexslider ul').wrapInner('');