# How to hover child nodes separately in ul element?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

HTML `ul` element hovers child with parent

```css
ul li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvt8xecz/)

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/yvt8xecz/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understood you are trying to achieve this:

- when having the children `li` hovered the parent still remains with the child's same style.

So here is a **SNIPPET**

```css
li {
  /* demo */
  list-style: none;
}
li:hover {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700
}
li:hover li {
  color: none;
  font-weight: 400
}
li:hover li:hover {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1 - text
    <ul>
      <li>1 - text</li>
      <li>1 - text</li>
      <li>1 - text</li>
      <li>1 - text</li>
      <li>1 - text</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1 - text</li>
  <li>1 - text</li>
  <li>1 - text</li>
  <li>1 - text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes!this is solution too.Thank you.And it is even clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <ul>
    <li>1<ul>  << this Line Error

            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

## Fixed Code

```css
ul li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: my ide wrote UL element not allowed in UL.

Comment: This HTML is not valid. "Permitted content for <ul>: Zero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements."

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve you problem with slight change in html

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><span>1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>1</span></li>
      <li><span>1</span></li>
      <li><span>1</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>1</span></li>
          <li><span>1</span></li>
          <li><span>1</span></li>
          <li><span>1</span></li>
          <li><span>1</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>1</span></li>
      <li><span>1</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
  <li><span>1</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li span{
  display:block;
}
ul li:hover > span {
  background-color: pink;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/yvt8xecz/3/

> With added span you don't need to fight with ul li structure just change the color of span

Answer (score 1):

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
li:hover li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
valid HTML

Comment: try multi ul then  you will see issue.

Comment: I did't understand what do you change? :D And i am looking for solving without many ul ul ul,because my tree will be added dynamically and i don't know how many children will be.

Comment: i moved around the li elements so there were all separate but i see that is not quite what you are after i suggest looking at @GauravAggarwal answer as i think he has what you want

Comment: is it valid html ?

Comment: **Error: Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)**...This is the error with w3c validator. This is not correct html `<ul>` should be inside `<li>` according to standards.

Comment: is ul allowed as direct child of li ?

Comment: @afelixj yes..check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ul li ul li:hover{
  background-color:pink;
}
```