# PHP array get each 5 in a list

Tags: php, arrays, list

$cars = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");

I need to get 2 col-lg-2 for each 5 rows inside this structure:

$car

how can it done ?

for the first 5 rows i made this:

```
<div class='col-lg-2'><ul>
<?php $i=0;
foreach($cars as $car){
  echo "<li>$car</li>";
  $i++;
  if($i==5) break;
} ?>
</ul></div>
```

how can I echo the next 5 ?

Comment: use modulus http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: you're using `as $car` but not using it and `$car_name` is undefined. Your code makes no sense.

Comment: man its just an example !!!!!!!   --- the modulus that you said before may can work. i trying to check it. thank you.

Comment: You example should work in order to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: edited .. thank you!

Comment: For tasks like this use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and stop producing ridiculous code with obscenities like modulus.

Comment: hummmm .... i going to check that @KaloyanDoichinov thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `array_chunk()`

By using `array_chunk()` you can generate a multi-dimensional array, with 5 elements in each.

```
$cars = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
$carsGrouped = array_chunk($cars, 5);
foreach($carsGrouped as $carGroup){
 echo "<div class='col-lg-2'><ul>";
 foreach($carGroup as $car) {
    echo "<li>{$car}</li>";
 }
 echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

https://eval.in/652005

#### Using Modulus

By using the modulus operator (`%`) you can check if your counter (`$i`) is divisible by `5`, and if it is, then end the current `<div>` and start a new `<div class='col-lg-2'>`.

```
$cars = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
echo '<div class=\'col-lg-2\'>
        <ul>';
$i = 0;
foreach($cars as $car){
    ++$i;
    echo '<li>'. $car .'</li>';
    if($i>1 AND ($i%5)===0 AND $i<count($cars)) { //We've printed 5 $car, we need to do another "group".
        echo '</ul>
           </div>
           <div class=\'col-lg-2\'>
               <ul>';
    }
} 

echo '</ul>
  </div>';
```

https://eval.in/651965

Comment: @MinaMagdy updated answer to include another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the modulus division operator as suggested, here is a possible solution;

```
$cars       = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "s", "ee");
$iCount     = 0;
$sOutput    = '';

foreach($cars as $sCarName){

    if ($iCount % 5 == 0)
       $sOutput .= ($iCount > 1 ? "</ul>\n</div>\n" : '')."<div class='col-lg-2'>\n<ul>\n";

    $sOutput .= "<li>".$sCarName."</li>\n";

    $iCount ++;
}

if( $iCount > 1 ){
    $sOutput .= "</ul>\n</div>";  
} 

echo $sOutput;
```

N.B. its not valid html to have a `div` as a child of an `UL`, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul)

Comment: great, will update in 5 to include valid html output :)

Comment: *"I need to get 2 col-lg-2 for each **5 rows** inside this structure"* - this gives 4 in the first group.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$cars = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J");
?>
<div class='col-lg-2'><ul>
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach($cars as $car_name){
echo "<li>$car_name</li>";
$i++;
if($i==5): 
    echo "</ul></div><div class='col-lg-2'><ul>";
    $i = 0;
endif;
} 
?>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.