# CSS active class not working for tab content

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the left border of the list item with `Link` text to red on active, and when the user clicks another list item, the previous border is set to the original and the successive list item is then set to a red left border. I tried with an `:active` class, but that is not working correctly:

```
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" aria-expanded="false">Link</li>
      </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-group li:active {
  border-left: 3px solid #ce2523;
  padding-left: 7px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/vxz7zrg9/)

Comment: Your HTML markup is completely invalid, whether that factors in to what you're attempting at all. The only element that's an acceptable child to `<ul>` is `<li`> - not `<div>`. I'd suggest putting your `<div>` in an `<li>` and straightening out any HTML issues before moving on to addressing CSS

Comment: No, the left border flashed red when clicking the link, but I need it to stay red when active.

Comment: ...And what I'm saying is that before you start moving on to CSS, you should correct your HTML. Wouldn't you rather fix the foundation before building a house on it?

Comment: I've simplified the markup, so its just a matter of how to set the `li` left border to red on click (not just hover).

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/vxz7zrg9/3/ - And as a supplement to what I mentioned above, take a look at this: [Can I use DIV as a direct child of UL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to achieve that.

- remove :active
- create a class .cative with the same css like before you had fro :active
- Create a jQuery to toggle class `active`

<kbd>[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pn8ybm1c/)</kbd>

```js
$('.list-group li').on('click', function() {
  $('.list-group li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.active {
  border-left: 3px solid #ce2523;
  padding-left: 7px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 question-list">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" aria-expanded="false">Link</li>
        <li class="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#21" aria-expanded="false">Link</li>
        <div id="2" class="tab-content collapse mobile-answer">
          <p class="header">content of link</p>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Bunch o' content here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div id="21" class="tab-content collapse mobile-answer">
          <p class="header">content of link</p>
          <div class="answer">
            <p>Bunch o' content here</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's really close. How can I set it to remove the active class from all other list items before applying it to the currently selected item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this as I don't think it is possible with the pure CSS if you're using Bootstrap collapse.

```
$('.tab-content').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).prev('li').removeClass('liborder');
})

$('.tab-content').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
     $(this).prev('li').addClass('liborder');
})
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vxz7zrg9/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to add an `<a>` tag around your "Link" text, you can achieve this using pure CSS:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

li a,
li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.list-group li a:focus {
  border-left: 3px solid #ce2523;
  padding-left: 7px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" aria-expanded="false">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" aria-expanded="false">
    <a href="#">Another Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```