# Style div as zebra

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems trying to style div tags on my code, you can check in the following jsfiddle what I have.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/k3c1ebc3/)

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  line-height: 25pt;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="cb-list">
  <div class="container">
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          First Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          Second Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I'm using a tool that is generating the code automatically, so I'm not able to change this code. I have tried with using nth-of-type and nth-child both with odd and even but no luck yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Problem #1 is that the HTML you're dealing with is invalid. A `<div>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`. Only a `<li>` can

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I accomplish alternate backgrounds for divs in this case? Would it be possible then to color li tags instead of divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for not changing the html.**

The class you want to alter is inside the li, not the div,
you miss 1 level in your code.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  line-height: 25pt;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.container li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.container li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cb-list">
  <div class="container">
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          First Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          Second Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: According to the OP "I'm not able to change this code"

Comment: @j08691 , you are right, updated for just changing css only

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you properly, you are trying to pick first div inside each odd  list item and each even list item

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  line-height: 25pt;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.container li:nth-of-type(odd) div {
  background: red;
}

.container li:nth-child(even) div{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cb-list">
  <div class="container">
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          First Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="detail">
          Second Record
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

> I'm using a tool that is generating the code automatically, so I'm not
>   able to change this code

but div inside ul is invalid [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Yeah, but OP said the code can't be changed, so ya gotta take it or leave it. +1 for a workable solution.

Comment: Yes, I can't change the html since the tool is generating automatically I just can change the css to deal with the requirement... Maybe a bug? Could be... The solution seems OK... +1