# HTML elements not returning to original state after media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**(I'm farely sure the issue has been fixed now. Thanks to the people that helped me. The issue was that I had put  elements as direct child elements of a  element.)**

This is my first time making a StackOverflow ask so please do bear with me.

I'm currently working on a website and have run into a problem while adding media query's. On the screen are five buttons like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzCxE.png).

When changing making the width of the browser window smaller, the buttons adapt to follow the media query rules like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGTgb.png). Everything is going as expected so far.

The issue then occurs when increasing the browser window width. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ttQG.png). In hopes of a result, I'll inform you of the code I'm using.

The media query code is

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    #buttons {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #buttons li {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        float: none;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

and the default code is

```
#buttons {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: -50%;
}

#buttons li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 175px;
    font-family: 'Republikaps';
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-image: url('assets/images/blog_bg.png');
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

It'd be very much appreciated if somebody could help me solve this issue.

(PS: Unless I change it, here's a link to the [website](https://ahlgreen.net/EverythingHiveswap/index.html))

Comment: You have errors in your html, you should start by fixing them. This question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Comment: as @vicbyte wrote, fixing the markup also fixes the problem you are having. To point out what precisely the error is: The only allowed direct children of a `<ul>` are `<li>`s. You need to wrap the `<a>`s with the `<li>`s, not the other way round.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much.