# Add active class to <li> and leave it after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<script>
    $("li").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
      );
    </script>
```

In order to add class active to my li in a menu.

```
<ul class="list-first-level">
<div about="" typeof="" class="ds-1col entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-modulo-de-enlaces-item view-mode-modulo_de_enlaces_01_d clearfix">
        <li id="elm" class="active always">
            <a href="/grados/eng/">Undergraduate programmes</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/grados/eng/ged">Law</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I need to not remove the active class after Im not hover on the element.

Comment: just remove this line: `$(this).removeClass('active');` this is the mouseout event and you are telling it to remove the class within it.

Comment: You should remove the div inside your UL, as this is not valid markup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul

Comment: But then the last item hovered is always visible.

Comment: Please don't delete your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645268/li-always-active-after-hover), and ask the same question again. Instead of deleting, edit your question if needed.

Comment: @teemu sorry, i am a noob here

Comment: is the question how not to remove the active class if it is already active?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to begin with, you can not put a `div` as child of `ul`. And what you actually want seems rather unclear.

Comment: @pete What I want is to add class active when hover and keep that class when Im not hover any element.

Comment: Then your answer is below as it does exactly what you just asked for

Comment: Iowry0031's answer does exactly what you want, and you say it's not working ..? I guess you want to have an active class on hovered elements, and if not hovering any `li`, then keep the last hovered `li` active?

Comment: @teemu, that is correct. But the code below is not working for me. Sorry for my english.

Comment: This is exactly what Im trying to do:
Section: A programme for every vision
https://www.esade.edu/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over an element, remove the 'active' class from all `li` elements then add it back to the current element. This still means that if the user moves away from the last, hovered element - that element will remain in an 'active' state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("li").hover(
        function () {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Although, you will end up with many active LI and does not provide a good UX.

Comment: Is not working, the last item hovered is always visible.

Comment: @JAVIERMARTINBALSA But this is an answer to your question.