# How can i change the li items to div? javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a ul class for a menu that joomla creates in my site but i dont want the li items inside, i want to transform them to div

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default uk-nav-parent-icon uk-nav-accordion" uk-nav="">

<li><a href="/aviso-legal">Aviso legal</a></li>
<li><a href="/politica-de-privacidad">Política de privacidad</a></li>
<li><a href="/politica-de-cookies">Política de cookies</a></li></ul>
```

I try this:

```
content.find(".uk-nav li>div").unwrap().wrap("<div>");
```

What i want at the end is:

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default uk-nav-parent-icon uk-nav-accordion" uk-nav="">

<div><a href="/aviso-legal">Aviso legal</a></div>
<div><a href="/politica-de-privacidad">Política de privacidad</a></div>
<div><a href="/politica-de-cookies">Política de cookies</a></div></ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vyfx1L8w/
Change also ul to div is ok, or ul to div and li to p

Comment: **Heads up**: `<div>` as a direct child of a `<ul>` is [invalid html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755628/can-i-use-div-as-a-direct-child-of-ul). Is there a particular reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: Change also ul to div is ok, or ul to div and li to p, i dont want the style of li in that item and joomla is doing it with no option of change.

Comment: Why not just style the list the way you want it with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, ensure you replace the UL also to ensure you still have valid HTML when you're done. Anyway, Since you're already using jQuery, you could do this;

```js
let content = $(".uk-nav").html();
content = content.replace(/<li>/g, "<div>");  
content = content.replace(/<\/li>/g,"<div>"); 
$(".uk-nav").html(content);
```

If you'd rather do this with vanilla javascript, this is also an option;

```js
let content = document.querySelector('.uk-nav').innerHTML;
content = content.replace(/<li>/g, "<div>");  
content = content.replace(/<\/li>/g,"<div>"); 
document.querySelector('.uk-nav').innerHTML = content;
```

To change the UL in to a div, do the same thing but target the UL's parent.

Comment: @David Sorry, I missed out a pretty important part. I've updated my answer to include the missing line. [Fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7j1gc8m/).