# Styling HTML Child Lists

Tags: html, css

I was testing `list-style-type` changes for child lists and noticed something strange happening. When you try and change the properties of a child list by using a selector like `li li` it will not work. If you remove the topmost selector in my below example, all styles are removed. If you inspect the element, the styles aren't being applied at all so it's not as though something is overwriting them.

```css
li {
  color: purple;
}
li li {
  color: red;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
li li li {
  color: blue;
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
li li li li {
  color: green;
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Parent List</li>
  <ul>
    <li>1st Child</li>
    <ul>
      <li>2nd Child</li>
      <ul>
        <li>3rd Child</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

When you replace `li` with `ul`, it works as you'd expect the above to. Why does all of this happen? I've never seen behaviour like this before.

```css
ul {
  color: purple;
}
ul ul {
  color: red;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
ul ul ul {
  color: blue;
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
ul ul ul ul {
  color: green;
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Parent List</li>
  <ul>
    <li>1st Child</li>
    <ul>
      <li>2nd Child</li>
      <ul>
        <li>3rd Child</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

## I am voting to close this as I'm an idiot and that's the extent of this. I'd hope you vote to close as well.

Comment: Did you mean to put your nested `ul` inside the `li`? You can't place a `ul` as a child of a `ul`.

Comment: @ksav you can. See https://jsfiddle.net/gh0ysrt8/1/

Comment: @ksav You can and it's how you're supposed to style child lists.

Comment: Take a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul under the Permitted content section.

Comment: Also this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755657/5385381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because using `li li` means a *child* `li` of an `li`. So in this case, that would apply to the second `li` below:

```
<li>
    <li>foo</li>
<li>
```

However, in your example, the nested lists are not inside an `li`, but instead by themselves, so they are not the children of any `li`.

Comment: `li li` styles a `li` element anywhere below another `li` element. If it was `li > li` then you would be correct but that is not the case. Change the selectors to `li > ul > li` and you'll see the problem still persist.

Comment: @Spedwards Actually, I am correct. From MDN: `The   (space) combinator selects nodes that are descendants of the first element. Example: div span will match all <span> elements that are inside a <div> element.`. In this case, that means that `li li` will only select `li`s that are inside another `li`, which none of yours are.

Comment: I don't think you understand how CSS selectors work. The selector `main ul` will apply styles to the element `ul` where it sits in the tree `<main><div><ul>`. See: https://codepen.io/Spedwards/pen/ZEGbprq

Comment: @Spedwards and that's what I'm saying. `li li` only applies to `li`s that are *inside* another `li`. In your case, all of the children list `li` are *not* within another `li`. That's why it doesn't work, and `ul ul` works - because the children `ul` are *inside* the parent `ul`.

Comment: They are within the `li` in the same way the `ul` is within `main` in the example of `<main><div><ul>`.

Comment: @Spedwards No, it's not. Take a look at your code. You have `<li>foo</li><ul><li>bar</li></ul>`. The `ul` and `li` are *not* within the first `li`, or any `li`.

Comment: Well crap. Now I feel stupid. My live code uses the correct format of `<ul><li><ul>` but when I was testing, I have what I've got in my question due to an error on my part. Sorry :/

Comment: @Spedwards Haha, no worries. We all make mistakes; sometimes it just takes someone pointing at it with 4 hands for you to see :)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, LIs are not getting nested in the `LIs` (they are not within each other - `<li><li>...</li></li>`. Hence, the styling of. `li li {...}` won't work at all.

The way your HTML is, it is nesting ULs. Hence, `ul ul {...}` styling will work.

Remember, in CSS to make `li li` work they should be nested within each other otherwise CSS won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just creating classes like `.green` `.red` `.blue` `.purple` and adding those classes to the `<li>` tags, because it has better re-usability.

I would recommend you to go trough the essentials of HTML5 again & work on your style of coding.

P.S Regarding your problem, here's another [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) that explains how to properly nest lists.